# Launching several long running background services at the same time

Tags: c#, .net-core, background-process, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I am experimenting with `IHostedService` in a `dotnet core 2.2`. My task is to create 2 background long-running tasks.

- The first of them is to manage `Selenium` browser session (open/close tabs, parse DOM) and put email messages in a queue inside `ConcurrentBag`.
- Second background worker is sending out email notifications once in 10 minutes, for the messages that exist in `ConcurrentBag` (which first task added). It also groups them together so that only 1 message is sent.

However, I am having troubles running 2 of the hosted processes at the same time. It seems like only first hosted process if being executed, while the second process awaits for the first to be fully executed. But since I never expect it to be finished - second process never starts...

Am I misusing the `IHostedService`? If yes, then what would be the best architectural approach of accomplishing my task?

Here is the code that I am currently using (trying to finish):

```
using System;
// ..

namespace WebPageMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ConcurrentBag<string> Messages = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args)
                .Run();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("emailSettings.json", optional: true);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddOptions();

                    var bindConfig = new EmailSettings();
                    hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings").Bind(bindConfig);
                    services.AddSingleton<EmailSettings>(bindConfig);

                    services.AddTransient<EmailSender>();

                    services.AddHostedService<BrowserWorkerHostedService>();
                    services.AddHostedService<EmailWorkerHostedService>();
                });

            return hostBuilder.Build();
        }

    }
}
```

BrowserWorkerHostedService

```
public class BrowserWorkerHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private static IWebDriver _driver;

    public BrowserWorkerHostedService()
    {
        InitializeDriver();
    }

    private void InitializeDriver()
    {
        try
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

            _driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Program.Messages.Add("Exception: " + ex.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine($" Exception:{ex.ToString()}");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stopToken)
    {
        while (!stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
                Program.Messages.Add("Successfully opened a website!");
                // rest of the processing here

                Thread.Sleep(60_000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.Messages.Add("Exception: " + ex.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(120_000);
            }
        }

        _driver?.Quit();
        _driver?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

EmailWorkerHostedService

```
public class EmailWorkerHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly EmailSender _emailSender;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public EmailWorkerHostedService(
        EmailSender emailSender,
        IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _env = env;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stopToken)
    {
        while (!stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            List<string> exceptionMessages = new List<string>();
            string exceptionMessage;
            while (Program.Messages.TryTake(out exceptionMessage))
                exceptionMessages.Add(exceptionMessage);

            if (exceptionMessages.Any())
            {
                foreach (var message in exceptionMessages)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(new string(message.Take(200).ToArray()));
                    builder.AppendLine();
                }

                string messageToSend = builder.ToString();
                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(messageToSend);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** After applying changes suggested in answer, here is the current version of the code that works. Adding `await` helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First DO NEVER use `Thread.Sleep()` in async context as it's blocking action. Use `Task.Delay()` instead. And I believe here is your problem. Look at [BackgroundService.StartAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs#L30) implementation:

```
    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Store the task we're executing
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

        // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
        if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return _executingTask;
        }

        // Otherwise it's running
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

When asyc method called actually it performed **synchronously** until first true async operation. Your true async operation is

> await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(messageToSend);

but it will be called only when meeting the condition

> if (exceptionMessages.Any())

It means your `ExecuteAsync` method will never return and so `StartAsync`.
`Task.Delay` is also true async method (`Thread.Sleep` is not), hence after hitting it the `StartAsync` will continue and exit and your second service will have the chance to start.

Comment: Great! Just updated my code and ran a couple of tests. It seems to be behaving the way it should. I feel like I need to dig into async processing a bit more, to better understand the internal logic. Thank you for help @Artur!

Comment: I'd also advice to override `StarAsync` and call there `InitializeDriver` and then call base implementation. This way you will separate object creation from initialization and debugging will be easier.

Comment: mind if I ask additional question? What would be an approach to end all running hosted processes gracefully at the same time, when a certain condition in "email service" is met?

Comment: Your `ExecuteAsync` receives `CancelationToken` - this token is canceled when service stopped. To trigger service stop you can use `IApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()'. But be aware that it will stop the whole web service.

Comment: in my scenario this is a preferable outcome :) Thanks! I tried using `Environment.Exit(0)` but it hanged the application.. Perhaps because of calling it from non-main thread..With the `IApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()` application quits as expected.

Comment: do you have a logical explanation why `Task.Delay()` might cause the `lifetime.ApplicationStarted.IsCancellationRequested` to be set to `true`? That is, even without `StopApplication()` method call. I will put the current code into description. In the example - the applciation will be aborted after first `Task.Delay()` call.

Comment: Please open new question and post link here in comment.

Comment: done https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955587/task-delay-triggers-cancellation-of-application-lifetime